# how to set parameter for robust regression?

Tags: r, machine-learning, regression, robust

I am using the `rlm` R package and experimenting with robust regression using the Huber function. Here is my code:

```
myfit= rlm(formula = depvar ~ indep1+indep2, init="ls",data = my_input_data,psi =psi.huber, k=0.99,method = "M", maxit=200)
```

`k` is the tuning parameter for the Huber function (`psi.huber`), which I set to `0.99` in my code above.

However, the default specified in the `rlm` R documentation is `k = 1.345`.

I would appreciate any insights if it is commonly acceptable in statistics to change this tuning parameter. And is there any way to automatically determine this parameter through some optimization?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this might give you some pointers how to interpret the value of `k`: http://www.iwaenc.org/proceedings/1997/nsip97/pdf/scan/ns970534.pdf `k` is a borderline value of central Gaussian part of the distribution. Depending on the data, you might want to reduce or increase efficiency of regressor estimator (1.345 corresponds to 95% efficiency: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/robustbase/vignettes/psi_functions.pdf).

Comment: thanks. When we say 95% efficiency....do we mean in terms of computation speed? that is, if k is reduced computation is faster?

Comment: Nope, it's a statistical efficiency (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Efficiency_(statistics) ). But explaining that in detail is a bit over my head, you might be better off if you try [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/).